# How to find the possible unknown on the given equation on GAP

Tags: gap, programming

How to find all positive integers A and B such that

$400*A+399*B=10026475$, where $A \in [1000..5963]$ and $B \in [0..A-1]$.

I tried on this way

```
total:=[];; 

for A in [1000..5963] do
for B in [0..A-1] do
f:=400*A+399*B;
if f=10026475 then
Print(f);
Add(total,f);
fi;
od;od;
gap> A;
5963
gap> B;
5962
```

But there are not all possible solutions of A and B.

Thanx in advance

Comment: I'm not sure MSE is the best place for this question, as it seems like your issue is in the code rather than with the math? Though you might be able to do better than just two brute-force loops. For instance, since $400A$ can only produce numbers ending in $00$, the $399B$ has to get you the last two digits. And because $100k+99$ is kinda special, only $1$ in $100$ values of $B$ will get you those last digits. That should give you a lot less to loop through.

Comment: I don't know GAP, but in Python something like `A= 5963; B = 25; tot=0; while B<A: A = (10026475 - 399 * B)/400; if int(A) == A: if 1000 <= A and A<= 5963: tot += 1 .... B+= 100` Sadly I can't do proper code indenting in a comment. Also... there are *no* solutions in the range given.

Comment: Try [code review se](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) or [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $400\cdot 5963+399*5962=4764038\ll 10026475$ this equation has no solution as specified.